# how to pass java variable inside javascript function?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, servlets

javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function submitform(){
    //  alert("inside submit");
    <% String username1=(String)session.getAttribute("UserName");

    if(username1 == null || username1.equals("undefined")){%>
        alert("please login to submit");
    <% }else{ %>
        //alert("In Submit form");

        var frm=document.getElementById("myForm");
        frm.action="Electionservlet?formidentity=editYPName&Username="+<%=username1%>;
        //alert("before submit");
        frm.submit(); 

    <%}%>
}

</script>
```

when i click on the submit button the abobe function('submitform') is called.
so what i want here is how can i pass a java variable(username1) through javascript function and get that value inside my servlet???

Comment: Is this code in a JSP file or a plain JS file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*As `<%=username1%>` is not a javascript variable so you cant use `+` like that*

```
frm.action="Electionservlet?formidentity=editYPName&Username=<%=username1%>";

                                                              ^--------// removed +
```

Comment: frm.action="Electionservlet?formidentity=editYPName&Emailfb=<%=emailid%>&Username<%=username1%>";

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Expression Language in jsp to assign your attribute to a js variable and avoid the scriptlets. It will make your code more readable.

```
function submitform(){
    //  alert("inside submit");
    var username1=${sessionScope.UserName};

    if( username1 == null || username1 == "undefined" ){
        alert("please login to submit");
    }else{
        //alert("In Submit form");
        var frm=document.getElementById("myForm");
        frm.action="Electionservlet?formidentity=editYPName&Username="+username1;
        //alert("before submit");
        frm.submit(); 

    }
}
```

Comment: -1 UserName is not yet on the server-side. Its in a form-input in the browser. I always comment downvote, i am not that fast keypresssuperhero

Comment: `<% String username1=(String)session.getAttribute("UserName");` Username is being retrieved from session. So its supposed to be on the server.